# Find difference between different dates which are formatted differently

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables `claims` which has ptid, date_entered(date) and `customer_details` which has ptid, first_transaction_date(varchar). The date_entered in `claims` table is formatted YYYY-MM-DD and the first_transaction_date in the `customer_details` table is formatted YYYYMM.

GOAL: For all the unique ptid's in the claims table I want to find the difference between the first_transaction_date and date_entered in number of days. I want to see what customers have been in the system for a year, two years before entering the rewards program.

I am having problems with:
1. the different data types 
2. differences in formatting

This is what I have:

```
drop table if exists claims_1;

select a.* ,  b.diag_min, diag_min - first_month_active::date as start_dif
into claims_1
from claims as a
left join customer_details as b on a.ptid = b.ptid
where start_dif >= 0 and end_dif >= 0;
```

When I try to use str_to_date to convert the datatypes I get this error:

(500310) Invalid operation: function str_to_date(character varying, "unknown") does not exist;

```
select date_format(str_to_date(first_month_active, '%Y%m'), '%Y-%m')from customer_details
```

Comment: You asked this yesterday and that question was marked as a duplicate - are you having some problem with the str_to_date function? You should also read up https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub (and other date functions), Please add sample data and expected output as text to the question.

Comment: Yes I am getting this error: Invalid operation: function str_to_date(character varying, "unknown") does not exist

Comment: Please add the full error message including the error code.

Comment: and the code where you actually use str_to_date

Comment: Are you *really* using MySQL? This looks like a Postgres error.

Answer (score 1):

In postgresql, to convert string into date, use `to_date`:

```
 SELECT to_date('20190103','YYYYMMDD');
```

So you need,

```
 SELECT to_date(first_month_active, 'YYYYMM') from customer_details
```

And, to format a date into string, you need `to_char`, so final query will be,

```
 SELECT to_char(to_date(first_month_active, 'YYYYMM'), 'YYYY-MM') from customer_details
```

Comment: When I use this with an update statement ``` UPDATE customer_details
SET first_month_active = to_char(to_date(first_month_active, 'YYYYMM'), 'YYYY-MM') ``` I am getting this error: (500310) Invalid operation: Value too long for character type. Is there a way I can add this into the code where I take the difference?